# How to "pass" a variable value to a JSON dynamic object?

Tags: c#, json, .net

I dont know how to correctly say it, that´s why i wrote "pass" (please correct me).
What i am trying to do is to retrieve a value from an JSON object depending on another variable value

This is the code

```cs
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string list = client.DownloadString("https://linkto.json");
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(list);
var2 = json.variable[0].image;
```

It needs to read the variable value where it says "variable" but im not sure if this is possible or if it´s done in another way

Another edit: The "variable" on the code is where the variable should be read, i don't know either how to make it to read the value or anything

I tried searching on this forum and on the internet but im not sure what to search or what should i use

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Edit:

Here is the JSON string

```json
{
  "Person1": [
    {
    "image": "http://linktoimage.com",
    "icon": "http://linktoicon.com",
    "background": ""
    }
  ],
  "Person2": [
    {
    "image": "https://linktoimage",
    "icon": "",
    "background": "no-background"
    }
  ]
}
```

A short example of the JSON string

Another edit: The JSON string can change over time, with new arrays

Comment: You mean you know your json object will have an array attribute named "variable" and you want to get the image attribute of its first element ? Could you provide the details (a part of your json object copied here to make this clearer) please?

Comment: Have you tried json[0].image? It’s difficult to tell without knowing the json string

Comment: @Gigs im gonna edit the question with the json string

Comment: @Gigs and yes that is what i mean

Comment: @MrCoolAndroid Do you want to be able to specify "Person1" or "Person2" to be pulled at runtime? Is that what you need?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary yeah, also the json can change over time i forgot to say that, so i think that making classes wont be the best idea

Comment: The objects stay the same as in only the "Person1" key changes and the inner object stays the same?

Comment: As in, will `Person1` become `Person495845` at some point and you will know that you will have `Person495845` in a variable to then get their data?

Comment: not exactly, person1 will stay, there just will be more persons because i will be updating the json with more

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So i managed to do this by modifying the JSON format, i did it like this

```json
{"People":[
{
         "name": "",
         "icon": "",
         "background": ""
},
{
         "name": "",
         "icon": "",
         "background": ""
},
{
        "name": "",
        "icon": "",
        "background": ""
}]
}
```

So then I can use Foreach to get to the value

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use data is to deserialize your downloaded json

```
string json = client.DownloadString("https://linkto.json");
var jsonDeserialized= JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, List<PersonImage>> >(json).ToList();
List<Person> persons = jsonDeserialized.Select(j => new Person { Name = j.Key, Images = j.Value }).ToList();
```

persons in jason format

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Person1",
    "Images": [
      {
        "image": "http://linktoimage.com",
        "icon": "http://linktoicon.com",
        "background": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Person2",
    "Images": [
      {
        "image": "https://linktoimage",
        "icon": "",
        "background": "no-background"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

test, the first image of person who has a name "Person1"

```
var image=persons.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name=="Person1").Images[0].image; // http://linktoimage.com
```

classes

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PersonImage> Images {get;set;}
}
 public class PersonImage
{
    public string image { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string background { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i would do that but there is just too much arrays, i used the person as an example of the array, i would use a class but there are many

Comment: @MrCoolAndroid It is just an example how to do this. I didn' t know what was in your mind.  You can add more properties to these classes or  you have to post the real json if it is different. You can' t  use any dynamic  to deserialize json.

Comment: what im really trying to do is to get the object value depending on a variable as i said but that json can change over time so i would need to compile every time the json changes

Comment: @MrCoolAndroid Everything is changing over the time, you will never make an application that will be the same forever. Any application needs a support, and code is changing almost everyday before of bugs and changes of functionality.

Comment: yeah of course, but just saying that it will have at least 300 arrays or more

Comment: @MrCoolAndroid This code is universall , it will be working doesnt matter how many items do you have.

Comment: Yeah but i would like to update the JSON anytime i need to, like just taking my phone and then i just add an array and i dont have to update the app everytime

Comment: @MrCoolAndroid Yes, but code like this var2 = json.variable[0].image; doesn't make any sense at all  and nobody will ever use it.

Comment: yeah that's why i asked if there's a way to pass a variable, i used that code to show where it should go or where it needs to read the variable but as I said I don't know a way to pass a variable

Comment: @MrCoolAndroid If it would be easy to make an universal seializer for any json, nobody would spent time creating code for common simple case and making custom serializators for each anusuall  case.